# Angular get the data of the selected row in the table

Tags: angular

Angular4 is also given * ngFor tabloda is listed. I want to get 'ID' information from incoming data. How can I do that?

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of empleyoo">
        <th scope="row" >{{item.Id}}</th> /*this row data get*/
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.code}}</td>
       <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></button>
    </tr>       
<tbody>
```

**Typescript**

```
public GetId()
{
    var id=
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is not clear but I guess all you want is:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of empleyoo">
        <th scope="row" >{{item.Id}}</th> /*this row data get*/
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.code}}</td>
       <button type="button" (click)="onSelect(item)"class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></button>
    </tr>
<tbody>);

onSelect(selectedItem: any) {
    console.log("Selected item Id: ", selectedItem.Id); // You get the Id of the selected item here
}
```

Comment: @Faly I want the same thing but on row click not on button click is it possible?

Comment: @Pramod Yes, just put the event binding `(click)="onSelect(item)` on the row tag: `<tr *ngFor="lett item of empleyoo" (click)="onSelect(item)> ... </tr>`

Comment: @Faly what if there is no button and have to find from editable table td value?